# join 2 table orders wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins, mysql

i have two table wp_wcfm_marketplace_orders
wp_wcfm_affiliate_orders

i need call data where wp_wcfm_affiliate_orders.orderid wp_wcfm_marketplace_orders.order_id 
[image]
[image]

it code call data table wp_wcfm_affiliate_orders

```
    public function processing() {
        global $WCFM, $wpdb, $_POST, $WCFMu, $WCFMaf;

        $length = $_POST['length'];
        $offset = $_POST['start'];

        $affiliate_id = $_POST['wcfm_affiliate']; 
        $status          = $_POST['status_type'];

        $sql  = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}wcfm_affiliate_orders`";
        $sql .= " WHERE 1=1";
        $sql .= " AND {$wpdb->prefix}wcfm_affiliate_orders.affiliate_id = {$affiliate_id}";
        if( $status ) $sql .= " AND {$wpdb->prefix}wcfm_affiliate_orders.commission_status = '{$status}'";
        $sql .= ' AND `is_trashed` = 0';
        $affiliate_count = $wpdb->get_var( $sql );

        // Get Product Count
        $sql  = "SELECT  * FROM  {$wpdb->prefix}wcfm_affiliate_orders  ";
        $sql .= " WHERE 1=1";
        $sql .= " AND {$wpdb->prefix}wcfm_affiliate_orders.affiliate_id = {$affiliate_id} 

        ";
        if( $status ) $sql .= " AND {$wpdb->prefix}wcfm_affiliate_orders.commission_status = '{$status}'";
        $sql .= ' AND `is_trashed` = 0';
        $sql .= " ORDER BY `ID` DESC";
        $sql .= " LIMIT {$length}";
        $sql .= " OFFSET {$offset}";


        $wcfm_affiliate_orders_array = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
        $wcfm_affiliate_order_count  = count( $wcfm_affiliate_orders_array );
```

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Get Product Count
        $sql  = "SELECT  wcfm_affiliate_orders.*, ya.order_id,ya.order_status FROM  {$wpdb->prefix}wcfm_affiliate_orders AS wcfm_affiliate_orders  LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}wcfm_marketplace_orders AS ya ON ya.order_id = wcfm_affiliate_orders.order_id ";
        $sql .= " WHERE 1=1";
        $sql .= " AND  wcfm_affiliate_orders.affiliate_id = {$affiliate_id}

```
    ";
    if( $status ) $sql .= " AND  wcfm_affiliate_orders.commission_status = '{$status}'";

    $sql .= " ORDER BY  wcfm_affiliate_orders.ID  DESC";
    $sql .= " LIMIT {$length}";
    $sql .= " OFFSET {$offset}";


    $wcfm_affiliate_orders_array = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
```